# Unable to type characters in LightSwitch fields on a Mac

Tags: macos, silverlight, google-chrome, visual-studio-lightswitch

Could anyone help me understand why, in Chrome on a Mac, I cannot type characters in LightSwitch fields. I am able to delete characters, or select from a drop down list, but typing new characters isn't possible. I already tried reinstalling Silverlight on the Mac.

No issues when connecting to the server from a Windows client.

Using Visual Studio 2012, Mac OS X V.10.6.8 and Silverlight 5.1.10411.0

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about problems with Chrome on a Mac specifically, but I know that there's been a problem with Chrome on PC's. I don't remember hearing about your particular problem though, just connecting to data.

I thought the Chrome problem had been fixed in the RTM of VS 2012, but I could be wrong. Maybe this article might help?

[Working Around The Chrome Data Loading Bug In Lightswitch 2012 Rc](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mattev/archive/2012/06/25/working-around-the-chrome-data-loading-bug-in-lightswitch-2012-rc.aspx)

If not, & you can reprodue the problem, you might need tpo submit a bug on the [Connect website](https://connect.microsoft.com/site1231/feedback/CreateFeedbackForm.aspx?FeedbackFormConfigurationID=4960&FeedbackType=1).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Yann; let me see it this fixes the issue. Otherwise I will submit it on Connect.

Comment: Justin, from the LS team, has stated in the question that you asked in the forum, that your particular version  of Mac OS is not supported, so that's more than likely your problem.

Comment: Thanks for asking Justin. FYI: I don't run into this particular issue when using Safari (Version 5.1.5) on the same Mac OS X V.10.6.8... It's only when using Chrome.